# How do I prevent my swf files being hotlinked, downloaded etc

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, security, .htaccess, swf

I have swf files that are embedded in a PHP page using SWFObject. These swf files are in the same directory as my PHP files. for example www.myurl.com/index.php embeds www.myurl.com/flashfile.swf, index.php and flashfile.swf are in the same directory. However I want to prevent people from being able to type in www.myurl.com/flashfile.swf and viewing the swf. I want the browser to deny access to this file unless it has been embedded by the PHP file. Should I move my swfs to another folder and protect this folder somehow - is this with the .htaccess file?

I am running Apache on a linux machine. While my main concern is for swf files I would like to protect graphics used on the site too.

all help appreciated thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$ yourdomain.com/goaway.jpg [NC,R,L]
```

Comment: most downloader's have "send referer as ..." option. just consider that. but something with php session backend & apache_rewrite will be better for bot/crawler/downloader check.

Comment: Thanks I have added this and tested and it works great. Thanks for pointing out about send referer as. How can I use PHP session to protect this further. Im not sure how to use a session to protect files, only pages.

Answer (score 5):

It's important to realize that certain content *must* be downloaded to be displayed, such as with graphics.  Anything you add to "prevent" them being downloaded will be limited.  Direct links, however, can be prevented in most cases but a clever script could still set REFERER.

Flash streamed from Flash server makes it more difficult to download and hot link as well.  For controlling Flash, this should probably be investigated.

I like Mike's solution though, I gave him +1.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that if it can be watched, it can be copied, all you can do it make it a little harder to copy/rip/whatever.